# How to display Toast in Android?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-asynctask, toast

I have a slider that can be pulled up and then it shows a map. I can move the slider up and down to hide or show the map. When the map is on front, I can handle touch events on that map. Everytime I touch, a `AsyncTask` is fired up, it downloads some data and makes a `Toast` that displays the data. Although I start the task on touch event no toast is displayed, not till I close the slider. When the slider is closed and the map is not displayed anymore the `Toast` appears.

Any ideas?

Well start the task

**EDIT:**

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView){ 
    if (event.getAction() == 1) {
        new TestTask(this).execute();
        return true;            
    }else{
        return false;
    }
 }
```

and in `onPostExecute` make a toast

```
Toast.makeText(app.getBaseContext(),(String)data.result, 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

In new `TestTask(this)`, this is a reference to `MapOverlay` and not to `MapActivity`, so this was the problem.

Comment: this post was answered long time ago, but I think my comment may still help somebody. there is well-formed library related to `Toast`, check it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18280318/1891118

Comment: Almost all about Toast... simple tutorial....[click  here](https://androidride.com/how-to-use-toast-in-android-example/)

Answer (score 902, accepted):

In order to display [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) in your application, try this:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), (String)data.result, 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Another example:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This is my Toast message!",
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

We can define two constants for duration:

> int   **LENGTH_LONG** Show the view or text notification for a long period
>   of time.
>
> int   **LENGTH_SHORT**    Show the view or text notification for a short period
>   of time.

#### Customizing your toast

```
LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout, null);
Toast mytoast = new Toast(this);
mytoast.setView(view);
mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
mytoast.show();
```

Comment: @Elen, you need Activity context for making TOASTS, not Application context.

Comment: Actually, requiring an Activity context is not correct.  HOWEVER, getting toasts to work outside of activities (for example in a system Service) requires access to the main loop.  Posting my solution.

Comment: If you're putting it inside an onClick method, replacing getActivity() with getBaseContext() worked for me.

Comment: @PhilipBelgrave-Herbert Unfortunately your link is no longer good.

Comment: @IWannaKnow this is probably late haha but change getActivity() to your activity name

Comment: Unfortunately this answer does not work with the new version of android studio

Comment: Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 88):

Extending activity using `baseadapter` used this

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
    "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

or if you are using activity or `mainactivity`

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
    "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: there is no such thing like base adapter or main activity , toast only display by passing parameter app context, message, duration-long/short

Answer (score 48):

## Syntax

```
Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
```

---

## Parameter Value

#### *context*

> `getApplicationContext()` - Returns the context for all activities running in application.
>
> `getBaseContext()` -  If you want to access Context from another context within  application you can access.
>
> `getContext()` - Returns the context view only current running activity.

#### *text*

> `text` - Return "STRING" , If not string you can use type cast.

```
 (string)num   // type caste
```

#### *duration*

> `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` - Toast delay 2000 ms predefined
>
> `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`  - Toast delay 3500 ms predefined
>
> `milisecond`  - Toast delay user defined miliseconds (eg. 4000)

---

***Example.1***

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "STRING MESSAGE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

***Example.2***

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "STRING MESSAGE", 5000).show();
```

Comment: User defined 5000 millisecond toast delay.

Comment: Good explain, but you need Activity context for making TOASTS, not Application context.

Comment: Well, well, a cast such as (string)num has not yet been introduced to Java. Try Integer.toString() or similar.

Comment: **setting duration is not possible for a toast, only the predefined times, LENGTH_SHORT  & LENGTH_LONG**.

Answer (score 31):

To toast in Android,

```
import android.widget.Toast;


Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOUR MESSAGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOUR MESSAGE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

( LENGTH_SHORT and LENGTH_LONG are acting as boolean flags - which means you cant sent toast timer to miliseconds, but you need to use either of those 2 options )

Comment: Read the documentation, you will only choose either Toast.LENGTH_SHORT or Toast.LENGTH_LONG for the message duration.

Answer (score 21):

You can customize your toast:

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_file, null);
Toast toast = new Toast(this);
toast.setView(view);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
```

Or General way:

```
Toast.makeText(context,"Your message.", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Right - here are some examples from real projects on GitHub - http://www.codota.com/android/methods/android.widget.Toast/show

Answer (score 15):

I have tried several toast and for those whom their toast is giving them error try

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "google", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 14):

There are two ways to do it.

Either use the inbuilt Toast message

```
//Toast shown for  short period of time 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//Toast shown for long period of time
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

or make a custom one by providing custom layout file

```
Toast myToast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
myToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
myToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
myToast.setView(myLayout);
myToast.show();
```

Comment: Good explain, but you need Activity context for making TOASTS, not Application context.

Comment: The android docs specifically mention application context: "This method takes three parameters: the application Context, the text message, and the duration for the toast. It returns a properly initialized Toast object."

Answer (score 9):

I ran across the answers here, and was attracted by the fact that there seems to be someone poking around, believing that an Activity context is required.  This is not the case.  However, it is a requirement that a Toast is posted from the main event or UI Thread.  So, getting this to work outside of an activity context is a little bit tricky.  Here is an example that would work inside of a system service, or any potential class that ultimately inherits from `Context`.

```
public class MyService extends AccessibilityService {

    public void postToastMessage(final String message) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note that we do not need access to an instance of `Activity` for this to work.  Please stop suggesting this is the case!  If `Activity` were required, the method signature wouldn't call for a `Context`.

Answer (score 8):

```
Toast.makeText(app.getBaseContext(),"your string",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

instead of using "app.getBaseContext()".

You can try using "**getApplicationContext()**" or "**getContext()**".

If your code is in activity then you should use "this" of "Activty.this".
If your code is in fragment then you should go for "getActivity()"

Answer (score 7):

If it's fragment,

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 6):

For displaying Toast use the following code:

`Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());`

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);

toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

toast.show();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); // last two args are X and Y are used for setting position
 toast.setDuration(10000);//you can even use milliseconds to display toast
 toast.show();**//showing the toast is important**
```

Answer (score 5):

## Simple Way

#### `toast("Your Message")`

OR

#### `toast(R.string.some_message)`

Just add two methods in your `BaseActivity`. Or create new `BaseActivity` if you are not already using.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void toast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void toast(@StringRes int msg) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and extend all your activities by `BaseActivity`.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity
```

Answer (score 4):

[image]

[Must read: Android Toast Example](https://androidride.com/how-to-use-toast-in-android-example/)

**Syntax**

```
Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
```

You can use **getApplicationContext()** or **getActivity()** or **MainActivity.this**(if Activity Name is MainActivity)

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hi I am toast",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

or

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Hi I am Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 4):

**Inside Fragments (onCreateView)**

`Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "your message" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

**Inside Classes (onCreate)**

`Toast.makeText(myClassName.this, "your message" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way! (To Display In Your Main Activity, replace First Argument for other activity)

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Toast Message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "your text here" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
```

Answer (score 3):

The Getting Started Way

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one:

```
refreshBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),getText(R.string.refresh_btn_pushed),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Where `Toast` is:

`Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),getText(R.string.refresh_btn_pushed),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

& `strings.xml`:

`<string name="refresh_btn_pushed">"Refresh was Clicked..."</string>`

Answer (score 1):

#### Show Toast from Service

```
public class ServiceA extends Service {
    //....
    public void showToast(final String message) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
    //....
}
```

You can also put `showToast` method in your Application class, and show toast from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a simple toast in your activity:
`Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

1.Showing TextView in Toast:---

`TextView tv = new TextView(this);`
`tv.setText("Hello!");`
`tv.setTextSize(30);`
`tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);`
`tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);`

2.Showing Image as Toast:--

`ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);`
`iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.blonde);`
`Toast t = new Toast(this);`
`t.setView(iv);`
`t.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);`
`t.show();`

3.showing Layout as Toast:--

`LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();`
`View view = li.inflate(R.layout.my_toast_layout,null,false);`
`Toast t = new Toast(this);`
`t.setView(view);`
`t.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);`
`t.show();`

** If you want to write the toast in your Async then:
`private Activity activity;`
`private android.content.Context context;`
`this.activity = activity;`
`this.context = context;`
`Toast.makeText(context, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Answer (score 0):

Extension function with some kotlin sugar

```
fun Context.showToast(string: String){
    Toast.makeText(
        this, string,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
    ).show()
}
```

Usage:

From Activity:
`showToast("toast)`

From Fragment:
`requiredContext().showToast("toast)`