# Android display toast

Tags: android, toast

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500197/how-to-display-toast-in-android)

But not works for me.

I am going to display `Toast`, in my code:

```
private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        Log.d("MyPhoneListener", state + "   incoming no:" + incomingNumber);

        if (state == 1) {

            String msg = "New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : " + incomingNumber;
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, duration);
            toast.show();

        }
    }
}
```

But i have compile time exception neither in `getApplicationContext()` or in `MainActivity.this` , or `getActivity()`.

What is the solution?

Comment: What is your exception? send it here. have you tried to you getBaseContext() instead of getApplicationContext().

Comment: try with youractivityname.this..

Comment: pass `Context context`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: @Ghkjnsadxzcx use getBaseContext() instead of getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass context from the activity in which you are calling the method,you need to change your code something like below

```
public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String incomingNumber) {

    Log.d("MyPhoneListener", state + "   incoming no:" + incomingNumber);

    if (state == 1) {

        String msg = "New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : " + incomingNumber;
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

now you need to `pass context along with int state and string number` like `youractivityname.this`

Comment: you can not do that, it will change the method signature

Comment: look at your answer bro you are doing the same thing

Comment: I was talking about the signature of the methof `onCallStateChanged`. You should not change its signature.

Answer (score 0):

You can all `getApplicationContext()` like that in your class `MyPhoneStateListener`. This method is not static so `getApplicationContext()` is like calling `this.getApplicationContext()`.  And your class `MyPhoneStateListener` does not extends a class with such method.

So the solution will be to add a field `Context mContext` to your class. Then add a construtor

```
public MyPhoneStateListener(Context context, ...some other arguments if you need then ...) {
     super();
     mContext = context;
     ...some other stuff if you need then...
}
```

Then you can make your toast :

```
enterToast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, duration);
```

Comment: then what are you doing her check your code. you are passing `"context"`, along with some other arguments

Comment: Yes in the constructor. Then reference this context in a field. The method `onCallStateChanged` is define in the super class `PhoneStateListener`. If you change its signature, it will not override the method from super class.

Comment: check the question, method is not overridden

Comment: Well check documentation, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onCallStateChanged%28int,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

instead of `getApplicationContext()` try with

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Youractivity.this, msg, duration);
```

if you have contentprovider then

```
getContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run on ui Thread:

1. get a reference to your activity
2. do this

   ```
           activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() {
               Toast.makeText(activity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       });
   ```