# How to display message Toast when opening App Android

Tags: android

I am doing reverse engineering in an App to translate it to my local language I would like to display a Toast message to be displayed when you open the App on Android

Example Toast text "translated by Crypton" <<< I want to put this message on Toast

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display Toast in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500197/how-to-display-toast-in-android)

Comment: Just search for "How to display Toast in Android" and you will get 100s of answers.

Answer (score 0):

XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/custom_toast_container"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="#DAAA"
        >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java file:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String str="Welcome TO MSIT";enter code here
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String str="translated by Crypton";
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```