# How to display toast correct in Android my app?

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio. I want show "correct" or "incorrect" using `Toast` in my app for the answers. How to show `Toast` messages? Below is my code:

```
public class LayarKuisUmumNo1 extends Activity {

Button bt;
TextView tv;
RadioGroup rg;
RadioButton rbu1, rbu2, rbu3, rbu4;

public static String question[] = { "Negara terluas keempat di dunia"};
String answer[] = { "Amerika"};
String opts[] = {   "Rusia", "Australia", "Amerika", "Indonesia" };
int position = 0;
public static int correct;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layar_kuis_umum_no1);

    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnextu1);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pertanyaanu1);
    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
    rbu1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbu1a);
    rbu2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbu1b);
    rbu3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbu1c);
    rbu4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbu1d);

    tv.setText(question[position]);
    rbu1.setText(opts[position]);
    rbu2.setText(opts[position + 1]);
    rbu3.setText(opts[position + 2]);
    rbu4.setText(opts[position + 3]);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioButton selectedans = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            String selectedanstext = selectedans.getText().toString();

            if (selectedanstext == answer[position]) {
                correct++;
            }
            position++;
            if (position < question.length) {
                tv.setText(question[position]);
                rbu1.setText(opts[position * 4]);
                rbu2.setText(opts[position * 4 + 1]);
                rbu3.setText(opts[position * 4 + 2]);
                rbu4.setText(opts[position * 4 + 3]);
            } else {
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LayarNilaiUmum1.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Your english is ok, no problem :). Just add Toast.makeText(context,"HELLO",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: please read documentation or search in internet, because many answer for your problem is exist. for checking string don't use `==` in java, use `.equals()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display Toast in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500197/how-to-display-toast-in-android)

Comment: i want to say thanks for everyone. now,my app is working. thanks for Opiatefuchs for shayan pourvatan for cafebabe1991

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RadioGroup rg;
    RadioButton rbut1;
    Button bt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                rbut1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, rbut1.getText().toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: i want to say thanks for you. now my app is working.

Answer (score 0):

The code to add Toast message is this,

```
    Toast.makeText(this, "ZOOM Or use Landscape mode",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Basically, the first parameter is the context, second one is the string that contains the message you want to display and the last parameter is the duration you want the message to be displayed for.