# How do I check if EditText has a value?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` and a `Button`.

I want if an `EditText` was empty when clicked on my `Button`. I want to show message as a toast, like "please enter a number".

Comment: Can we see an example of the code?

Comment: Duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290531/check-if-edittext-is-empty

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this:

```
boolean hasValue = editText.getText().length() > 0;
```

or

```
boolean hasValue = !editText.getText().toString().isEmpty();
```

or to make sure it doesn't contain only spaces:

```
boolean hasValue = !editText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty();
```

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest way to do this is `TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText())`
The reason I say this is the cleanest way is because:

- You avoid pointless conversion between `CharSequence` and `String`. Which creates an object. `editText.getText()` returns `Editable`, calling `toString()` creates an additional object which is not good. This method will also never return null in my experience.
- You get a `null` and a `length` check out of that. If you look at the code for `TextUtils.isEmpty()`, it basically checks if the `CharSequence` is `null` and length is zero.
- It avoids code duplication and the same method can be used with `String`s or `CharSequence` objects and `Editable` is an implementation of `CharSequence`.
- It's provided as part of the Android framework.

If you want to check the length of the trimmed String. Then use:

```
TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText()) 
            && TextUtils.getTrimmedLength(editText.getText()) == 0
```

If you want, you can create your own utility method to do this so you don't have to add such a long condition in your code repeatedly.

I would attached an `OnFocusChangeListener` to your `EditText` to check the change in value or a `TextWatcher` or both depending on how critical your requirement is. If your field had focus and lost it, do your validation with the `OnFocusChangeListener`, if your field has focus and the user is typing and delete the content or the content is too short, use `TextWatcher` to let them know.

Answer (score 1):

Use this on click of your button:

```
  EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(EditTextID);
    if(editText.getText().toString().length()==0) {
    Toast alert = Toast.makeText(context, toast_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    alert.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the onClickListener() of the button:

```java
int length = editText.getText().length();
if(length == 0)
{
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter a number",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: No problem! Please accept the answer if you found it to be correct/useful.

Answer (score 0):

you probably already found your answer, but for the ones who came here hoping to find an answer here is how its done:

you have to make a String object or Int object first then in your button function Click write this:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    String numberValue;
                    numberValue = yourEditText.getText().toString();
                    if (emailEtValue.matches("")){
                        Snackbar sbEmptyValue = Snackbar.make(view, "You must enter an Integer Value", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        sbEmptyValue.show();
                    } else {
                        //DO THE THING YOU WANT
                    }
}
```

you can also use **[Toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500197/how-to-display-toast-in-android)** but i prefer Snackbar because its cooler than **[Toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500197/how-to-display-toast-in-android)**.