# OnClickListener in a fragment

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app with two fragments. In one of the fragments, I have four ImageButtons and I want to add some ation to them.

So, in the Java file of that fragment I already have the code for OnClickListener but it's not working.

[image: Java file with errors]

Comment: alt + enter and You will see what is a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use View.OnClickListener like this

```
  public class felan extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote view.onclicklistener and it's working but when I click a button. it does nothing

Comment: This is my onClickListener code: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/cvxKbzb.jpg)

Comment: Well you wrote nothing in your case blocks. It just check the conditions, nothing more. You can see if a condition works by using 'Toast' or 'Log' in them. Write "Toast.makeText...". For toast guide you cab use this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20542766/5780236

Comment: But Toast.makeText is for showing text in a small popup and I don't want that. When clicking a button, I want that button to open a fragment

Comment: I meant if you want to test click events you can use toasts. Forr opening fragments unfortunatly i can not help too much becase i haven't worked with them.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
public class GeneresFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
```

The OnClickListener is a an `interface` of the View class (ImageView extends View).