# OnCLick: read the field name and print it out in TOAST

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm trying to read an element from the list shown below (using onClick), with the data being read from a JSON file, the data itself only holds strings. However, I'm having trouble actually registering the array elements to the onClick procedure.

I have absolutely no experience with JSON and am trying to familiarise myself with reading a JSON file and storing it in an Array (which I've done), but I then want to click the individual fields and make it do something.

below is what I have so far:

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final ItemFruit itemFruit = fruitList.get(position);


    holder.tvFruit.setText(itemFruit.getFruit());
    holder.tvPrice.setText(itemFruit.getPrice());
    holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //when item is clicked, TOAST displays the field name

        }
    });

}
```

**Image of array:**
[array of fruit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2EEq.jpg)

Any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display Toast in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500197/how-to-display-toast-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

put this inside onclick

```
 Toast.makeText(adapterContext, itemFruit.getFruit(), 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Here adapterContext you have to maintain at adapter level.

Create global variable

```
   Context adapterContext
```

on onCreateViewHolder initialize it

```
 adapterContext = parent.getContext();
```

and then use it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. When adding that, I get the error "cannot resolve symbol adapter context". Is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: No, As i told you before you have to maintain context at adapter level.

Comment: Just trying that now, thank you for your continued help

Comment: Perfect, that worked. On second glance, I had created a private context c but I had not initialised it. Thank you ever so much for showing me my mistake! Have a great day!

Comment: @JamesSon Why didn't you accept this as the answer then?