# Error 'Cannot resolve method makeText' when creating a Toast

Tags: java, android, android-studio, toast, android-toast

When I use this code here

```
Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, ""+accountKitError.getErrorType().getMessage());
```

I get a message Cannot resolve method 'makeText.
This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onError(AccountKitError accountKitError) {
    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "+accountKitError.getErrorType().getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation of Toast.makeToast ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display Toast in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500197/how-to-display-toast-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`makeText` method takes three parameters: the application `context`, the `text` message, and the `duration` for the toast. It returns a properly initialized Toast object. You can display the toast notification with `show()`, as shown in the following example:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

In your case, you were missing the `duration` and the `show()`, add them like this and it will work:

```
Toast.makeText(
    HomeActivity.this, 
    ""+accountKitError.getErrorType().getMessage(),
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
).show();
```

Here is a link to the docs for more information about Toasts:
  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts#java

Comment: Thank you very much!! Now it is working perfectly.